# Error when extracting words offset in perl

Tags: perl, offset

I have a program that read tow files, the first file contain terms (one, or multiterms) seprated by  semicolon (; ), the second file contain text, the goal is to determine the offset of the terms in the first file!

My program begin well fluctuating vacuum (correct offsset extracted 2 20, also 45 59 for quantum fields)    , but when extracting the offset for example for terms  **nuclear physics** (correct ofsset 396 411) my code generate 399 414!   or Fermionic fields (my code generate  138 154) but the correct is 135 151

The code used is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;use warnings;

my @a = ();
my @b = ();
my @aa = ();
my $l=0;
my $v=1;
my $g=0;
my $kh;
my $ligne2;
my $texte;

open(FICC, $ARGV[0]);

print "choose the name of the file\n";
my $fic = <STDIN>;

open(FIC1, ">$fic");

while (<FICC>) {
    my $ligne2=$_;
    $a[$l]=$ligne2;
    $l++;
}

my $aa;
my $ligne;
my $rep = "C:\\scienceie2017_train\\train2";
opendir(REP,$rep) or die "E/S : $!\n";

foreach my $kh (@a) {
    chomp($kh);

    if ($kh=~/.*\.txt/) {
        $texte=$kh;
        #print "$kh";
        print FIC1 "$texte";
    }

    @aa=split(/;/,$kh);
    #$u++;
    while(defined(my $fic=readdir REP)){
        my $f="${rep}\\$texte";
        open FIC, "$f" or warn "$f E/S: $!\n";
        while(<FIC>){
            $ligne = $_;
            chomp($ligne);
            #print FIC1 "@aa";

            foreach my $che (@aa) {
                $che =~ s/^\s+//; 
                $che =~ s/\s+$//;
                if ($ligne =~/\Q$che\E/) {
                    print FIC1 "T$v\tTask $-[0] $+[0]\t$che\n";
                    $v++;
                }
            }
            $v = 1; 
        }
        print FIC1 "\n";
        close FIC;
        goto che
    }
che:
}
```

The text is:

> A fluctuating vacuum is a general feature of quantum fields, of which the free Maxwell field considered in  [1–12] is but one example. Fermionic fields such as that describing the electron, also undergo vacuum fluctuations, consequently one expects to find Casimir effects associated with such fields whenever they are confined in some way. Such effects were first investigated in the context of nuclear physics, within the so-called “MIT bag model” of the nucleon  [13]. In the bag-model one envisages the nucleon as a collection of fermionic fields describing confined quarks. These quarks are subject to a boundary condition at the surface of the ‘bag’ that represents the nucleon’s surface. Just as in the electromagnetic case, the bag boundary condition modifies the vacuum fluctuations of the field, which results in the appearance of a Casimir force  [14–18]. This force, although very weak at a macroscopic scale, can be significant on the small length scales encountered in nuclear physics. It therefore has important consequences for the physics of the bag-model nucleon  [19].

The extracted terms are:

> fluctuating vacuum;general feature;quantum fields;free Maxwell;free Maxwell field;Maxwell;Maxwell field;Maxwell field;Maxwell field;field considered in ;considered in ;1–12;Fermionic fields;vacuum fluctuations;Casimir;Casimir effects;Casimir effects;Casimir effects;such fields;Such effects;nuclear physics;so-called “MIT;so-called “MIT bag;“MIT bag;“MIT bag model”;bag model”;fermionic fields;fermionic fields describing;boundary condition;nucleon’s surface;electromagnetic case;bag boundary;bag boundary condition;boundary condition;vacuum fluctuations;Casimir;Casimir force ;force ;14–18;macroscopic scale;small length;small length scales;length scales;nuclear physics;important consequences;bag-model nucleon ;

Comment: i put a complete example of searched terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must open your filesin UTF8

reaplce

```
open FIC, "$f" or warn "$f E/S: $!\n";
```

by

`open FIC, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "$f" or warn "$f E/S: $!\n";`

Comment: that works but, there is caracter not in utf8 that are lost

Comment: @NarimenDal: What characters do you think are "not in utf8"?

Comment: sorry for the late reply , if i turn the file to ANSI i have **dynamicsÂ** but in utf8 **dynamics** to there is some corrpted caracters :  cellâ€™s,  [4â€“12].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on your code, but when I run your provided data with my code, I get these results.

The 2 variables `@-` and `@+`, (`$-[0]` and `$+[0]`) are described in the [Variables-related-to-regular-expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions). (LAST_MATCH_START & LAST_MATCH_END)

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'A fluctuating vacuum is a general feature ... (rest of line)';

my @terms = split /;/, 'fluctuating vacuum;Fermionic fields;nuclear physics;bag-model nucleon';

for my $term (@terms) {
    while ($s =~ /$term/g) {
        print "$-[0] - $+[0] $term\n";
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
2 - 20 fluctuating vacuum
135 - 151 Fermionic fields
396 - 411 nuclear physics
983 - 998 nuclear physics
1063 - 1080 bag-model nucleon
```

Comment: I think that it'd be good to explain this, ie. what `@-` and `@+` are

Comment: I think you didn't change anything you replaced the if by while, and with my file i have these results `
138 - 154 Fermionic fields
399 - 414 nuclear physics`, maybe the operation of opening the file can change the final results

Comment: i executed you same code and i have a different result! >2 - 20 fluctuating vacuum
138 - 154 Fermionic fields
399 - 414 nuclear physics
1000 - 1015 nuclear physics
1080 - 1097 bag-model nucleon

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$string = "A fluctuating vacuum is a general feature of quantum fields, of which the free Maxwell field considered in  [1–12] is but one example. Fermionic fields such as that describing the electron, also undergo vacuum fluctuations, consequently one expects to find Casimir effects associated with such fields whenever they are confined in some way. Such effects were first investigated in the context of nuclear physics, within the so-called “MIT bag model” of the nucleon  [13]. In the bag-model one envisages the nucleon as a collection of fermionic fields describing confined quarks. These quarks are subject to a boundary condition at the surface of the ‘bag’ that represents the nucleon’s surface. Just as in the electromagnetic case, the bag boundary condition modifies the vacuum fluctuations of the field, which results in the appearance of a Casimir force  [14–18]. This force, although very weak at a macroscopic scale, can be significant on the small length scales encountered in nuclear physics. It therefore has important consequences for the physics of the bag-model nucleon  [19].";

@extracted_terms = ( "fluctuating vacuum", "Fermionic fields", "nuclear physics", "bag-model nucleon" );

for my $term ( @extracted_terms )
{
    $position = index $string, $term;

    printf ( "%s, %s\n", $position, $position + length($term) );
}
```